# Как внедрить свою реализацию бд в Openfire?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring, xmpp

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, открыл для себя новый протокол **XMPP**. В частности начал изучать реализующей его **Openfire**.

А теперь подскажите как можно внедрить свою готовую бд, со своими таблицами в **Openfire**. В **Openfire** мне не нужны таблицы, хранящие роли пользователей, но нужна таблица, которая будет хранить сообщения пользователей.

Извините за глупый вопрос, я новичок в этом деле.

Answer (score 0):

*Openfire* использует свою схему базы данных со своими таблицами, связями и прочим, однако это открытый проект и в общем случае вы можете склонировать репозиторий [с GitHub](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire) и изменить код так, как вам нужно, в том числе изменить схему хранения данных.

Comment: там проект огромный. на изучение его потребуется n-кол-во времени. Новичку это сделать не по зубам(

Comment: @Санаев зато будет знать инструмент досконально :)

Comment: вот нашел еще один сервер, реализующий xmpp. называется babbler . вы слышали о таком? Что можете о нем сказать?